# DRF caching is not working while using detail serializer different than default

Tags: python, django, caching, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework with `DetailSerializerMixin` from `drf-extensions` like this:

```
class MyClassViewSet(DetailSerializerMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyClassSerializer
    serializer_detail_class = MyClassDetailSerializer

    @cache_response(60*60*12, key_func=CacheKeyConstructor())
    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(MyClassViewSet, self).list(*args, **kwargs)
        # adding some data here
        return response

    @cache_response(60*60*12, key_func=CacheDetailKeyConstructor())
    def retrieve(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(MyClassViewSet, self).retrieve(*args, **kwargs)
        # adding some data here
        return response
```

Everything works as it should when I'm not using `DetailSerializer` - it caches the data from basic serializer and it works perfectly, but when I change it to use my `DetailSerializer` it is not caching. I have tried not to use `DetailSerializerMixin` and use `get_serializer()` method instead and replace it there but it has the same effect. I need list data to have only few parameters and detail to have it all so it's a big waste if I will need to add all this stuff to basic serializer. Any suggestions?

@Edit: Added KeyConstructors:

```
class CacheKeyConstructor(DefaultKeyConstructor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CacheKeyConstructor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bits['all_query_params'] = bits.QueryParamsKeyBit()
        self.bits['pagination'] = bits.PaginationKeyBit()
        self.bits['list_sql_query'] = bits.ListSqlQueryKeyBit()
        self.bits['format'] = bits.FormatKeyBit()

class CacheDetailKeyConstructor(DefaultKeyConstructor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CacheDetailKeyConstructor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bits['all_query_params'] = bits.QueryParamsKeyBit()
        self.bits['retrieve_sql_query'] = bits.RetrieveSqlQueryKeyBit()
        self.bits['format'] = bits.FormatKeyBit()
        self.bits['kwargs'] = bits.KwargsKeyBit()
```

Comment: Do you overwrite the get_serializer_class ?

Comment: @Roba DetailSerializerMixin does that, but I also tried to do that manually, but it's still not caching as it should.

Comment: I would suspect that you're missing some data in the key constructor when  using the detail queryset. The way I would approach it (in order to solve it): put a breakpoint in cache_response, with some condition to filter out only your class, and figure out why the key isn't there in the cache. I see no relation in the code between the DetailSerializerMixin and the cache_reponse wrapper.

Comment: I added key constructors

Comment: I'll think some more on this. Maybe create a gist to see how its working. There's nothing obvious which stands out... If there is nothing more added to the viewset, like pagination, filtering, ordering ... then you should be able to get away with a simple construct derived from CacheResponseMixin and DetailSerializerMixin. I'll post an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

If your viewset doesn't have pagination or filtering then you should be able to implement something like this:

```python
class MyClassViewSet(DetailSerializerMixin,
                     CacheResponseMixin,
                     viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet)
    serializer_class = MyClassSerializer
    serializer_detail_class = MyClassDetailSerializer
```

Their default implementation is to keep 5 minutes cache, but this would help us to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Actually it does include filters and lookup fields so it cannot be achived that easily

Comment: I'll have to take this offline and to debug it.